# Counting a 1 Column all Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

I'm trying to(Sum together) all values in the final column but not having much luck.

I have the following :

```
Id | final | Date
------------------
 1    236    02-11-14
 2     10    07-01-12
 3     58    09-02-10
```

I'm currently doing :

```
select count (final) 
from dates_table
```

which brings me back one column of `3`. I need the result to be 236+10+58 which equals 304

If anyone could help on this, it would be much appreciated. I have also tried the SUM Function.

From this it is possible for the following :

```
TABLE 1
 Id | final | Date
------------------
 1    236    02-11-14
 2     10    07-01-12
 3     58    09-02-10

TABLE 2
 Id | final | Date
------------------
 1     330    02-11-14
 2     5      07-01-12
 3     100    09-02-10
```

ADD both Table 1 and Table 2 Sum'd values, and then work out the AVG number from this and create this as another column average, THEN if table2 for example SUM'd original amount (before the AVG) is higher than Table 1 SUM'd amount create another column and print in that column 'Tbl2 has the higher amount' and vise verser if table 1 had the higher amount.

End result Column wise table would look like this :

```
  ID|date|tb1_final_amount|tb2_final_amount|Avg_Amount|Top_Score_tbl
```

Comment: Given, you have ID and date in your summary table - do you want the sums and average grouped by these values? (BTW: What's your date format - "mm-dd-yy"?) You specified just one "Avg_Amount" column? For which table do you need it? Or should it combine the values from both tables? Perhaps you could add actual values to the expected output - aligned with the data in Table1 and Table2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(final) from dates_table
```

`count()` counts the amount of rows, in your case 3.
`sum()` gives you the sum for all selected values.

Comment: If this is correct, mind confirming it by the green arrow? So it gets labeled as 'answered'.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT SUM(final) FROM ...` is correct.